# Understanding allocated memory addresses in array elements in C (gcc in Windows 10)

Tags: c, arrays, memory, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to get a grip on pointers and arrays in C. Now, I'm stuck on trying to figure out how my C compiler allocates memory for the elements in a two dimensional array. Here's my example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ar[2][2] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };

    printf("sizeof(int)      = %u\n-----\n", sizeof(int));

    printf("ar               = %p\n", ar);
    printf("ar + 1           = %p\n", ar + 1);
    printf("&ar              = %p\n", &ar);
    printf("&ar + 1          = %p\n\n", &ar + 1);

    printf("sizeof(ar)       = %u\n-----\n", sizeof(ar));

    printf("ar[0]            = %p\n", ar[0]);
    printf("ar[0] + 1        = %p\n", ar[0] + 1);
    printf("&ar[0]           = %p\n", &ar[0]);
    printf("&ar[0] + 1       = %p\n\n", &ar[0] + 1);

    printf("sizeof(ar[0])    = %u\n-----\n", sizeof(ar[0]));

    printf("ar[1]            = %p\n", ar[1]);
    printf("ar[1] + 1        = %p\n", ar[1] + 1);
    printf("&ar[1]           = %p\n", &ar[1]);
    printf("&ar[1] + 1       = %p\n\n", &ar[1] + 1);

    printf("sizeof(ar[1])    = %u\n-----\n", sizeof(ar[1]));

    printf("&ar[0][0]        = %p\n", &ar[0][0]);
    printf("&ar[0][0] + 1    = %p\n", &ar[0][0] + 1);
    printf("&ar[1][0]        = %p\n", &ar[1][0]);
    printf("&ar[1][0] + 1    = %p\n\n", &ar[1][0] + 1);

    printf("sizeof(ar[0][0]) = %u\n-----\n", sizeof(ar[0][0]));

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get on my system is:

```
sizeof(int)      = 4
-----
ar               = 0061FF20
ar + 1           = 0061FF28
&ar              = 0061FF20
&ar + 1          = 0061FF30

sizeof(ar)       = 16
-----
ar[0]            = 0061FF20
ar[0] + 1        = 0061FF24
&ar[0]           = 0061FF20
&ar[0] + 1       = 0061FF28

sizeof(ar[0])    = 8
-----
ar[1]            = 0061FF28
ar[1] + 1        = 0061FF2C
&ar[1]           = 0061FF28
&ar[1] + 1       = 0061FF30

sizeof(ar[1])    = 8
-----
&ar[0][0]        = 0061FF20
&ar[0][0] + 1    = 0061FF24
&ar[1][0]        = 0061FF28
&ar[1][0] + 1    = 0061FF2C

sizeof(ar[0][0]) = 4
-----
```

I understand why `ar` is 16 bytes in size; it should be able to hold 4 `int`s, which on my system is 4x4 = 16 bytes. This, I guess, is also why the difference in bytes between `&ar + 1` and `&ar` is (hex) 30 - 20 = 16.

What I don't understand is why the difference between `ar + 1` and `ar` is only 8 bytes. This would mean that the array can only hold 2 `int`s á 4 bytes.

I have the same problem understanding `ar[0]` and `ar[1]` as you can see in my code.

Shouldn't `ar + 1` and `&ar + 1` produce the same result?

Comment: You need to use () to set the order of precedence, [] has the highest precedence after (), your expressions will not be what you expect as they are currently written. eg. *ar[0] is not the same as (*ar)[0]

Comment: Good point, thanks. However, in my code, I want the address of ar[0], is it not sufficient with &ar[0] or should I use &(ar[0])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `ar` is an array. Hence, first of all, remember

- `ar` is type of `int [2][2]`, which is an array of array of `int`s
- `&ar` is of type `int (*)[2][2]`, i.e., pointer to an array of array of 2 `int`s.

That said, array type, in cases, decay to the pointer to the first element of the array.**<sup>Note</sup>**

So, in case of an expression like

```
ar + 1
```

is just the same as

```
(&(ar[0])) + 1;
```

which basically points to `ar[1]`.

> *What I don't understand is why the difference between `ar + 1` and `ar` is only 8 bytes*

So, the *"difference"* here, is by the size occupied by the elements of `ar[0]`, which is , 2 `ints`, which is, in your platform, 8 bytes. Result checks out.

On the other hand, for an expression like

```
&ar + 1;
```

it operates on the pointer type (as mentioned earlier), and points to the location one past the last element in the array. So, the *difference* is, for 2 arrays of 2 `int`s each, hence (2*2*4) = 16 bytes.

---

**Note:**

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [....]

Answer (score 2):

`ar`, when used in an expression, "decays" to a pointer to the first element. In this case, `arr + 1` gives arithmetic on a pointer of type `int (*)[2]`. Which points to an `int [2]` with size 8 bytes.

This rule of "array decay" is specified in C17 6.3.2.1 §3:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a
>   string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is
>   converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of
>   the array object and is not an lvalue

So when you type `&ar`, you get the special exception from the array decay rule, no decay takes place but you actually get an `int (*)[2][2]` as expected. And therefore `&ar + 1` gives 16 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

So:

```
sizeof(int) == 4
```

The following:

```
int ar[2][2];
```

is a 2D array.

We know that, `a[b]` is equal to `*(a + b)`. And `&*` is converted to nothing.

So:

```
&ar[1]
```

is equal to

```
(ar + 1)
```

here `ar` "decays" or "shall be adjusted" (read as: magically converts) into a pointer. A pointer to an array of two int elements, ie. `int (*)[2]`. So it's not an `int *` nor `int[2][2]` pointer but `int (*)[2]`. We know that

```
sizeof(ar) == sizeof(int[2][2]) == sizeof(int[2]) * 2 == sizeof(int) * 2 * 2
sizeof(*ar) == sizeof(*(int(*)[2]) == sizeof(int[2]) == sizeof(int) * 2
sizeof(**ar) == sizeof(**(*(int(*)[2])) == sizeof(*(int[2])) == sizeof(*(int*)) == sizeof(int)
```

So

```
(ar + 1)
```

is equal to (to the value):

```
(uintptr_t)ar + sizeof(*ar) * 1 == 
    (uintptr_t)ar + sizeof(*(int(*)[2])) * 1) ==
    (uintptr_t)ar + sizeof(int[2]) * 1) == 
    (uintptr_t)ar + sizeof(int) * 2 * 1)
```

ie. it increments the `ar` pointer value by `2 * sizeof(int)`.

> What I don't understand is why the difference between ar + 1 and ar is only 8 bytes.

`ar + 1` is equal to

```
(uintptr_t)ar + sizeof(*ar) + 1
```

As `ar` is `int[2][2]`, then `*ar` is `int[2]`, so `sizeof(*ar) = sizeof(int) * 2`.
So `ar + 1` is equal to

```
(uintptr_t)ar + sizeof(int) * 2 * 1
```

So `(ar + 1) - ar` is equal to

```
((uintptr_t)ar + sizeof(int[2]) * 1) - (uintrpt_t)ar ==
    sizeof(int[2]) == 
    sizeof(int) * 2
```

> Shouldn't ar + 1 and &ar + 1 produce the same result?

In case of arrays like `int array[2];` The `array` pointer value is equal to `&array` pointer value. It is a quirk of C, that applying the address-of operator to an array results in array pointer to the same memory. Through `array` has a type of `int[2][2]`, but `&array` has the type of `int(*)[2][2]`, ie. it is a pointer to 2d array.

Because the type changes, the pointer arithmetics changes. Teh `typeof(ar)` decays to `typeof(int(*)[2])` so the `ar + 1` is equal to

```
`(uintptr_t)ar + sizeof(int[2]) * 1`.
```

But because the `typeof(&ar) == typeof(int(*)[2][2])` the `&ar + 1` is equal to

```
`(uintrpt_t)ar + sizeof(int[2][2]) * 1`.
```

hence the difference in pointer value when incrementing the pointer, as `sizeof(int[2][2])` is equal to `sizeof(int) * 2 * 2`.

I think you fail to grasp that in case of 2d arrays, the "first" level is 1d array of two elements, than the second is an int. So `typeof(ar[0])` is an array of two int elements.

Your code has UB, as the `%p` modifer should be used only with `void*` pointers. It's best to remember (or at least know that you should) to `printf("%p", (void*)&ar[1][0] + 1);` cast your pointers.